# How do I get this formula to increment by 1 per 25?

Tags: google-sheets

I need my formula to increase by "1" for every "25".  I wrote the following formula, but it does not work:

```
=SUM(
IF(O11<25,0,
IF(O11<50>21,1,
IF(O11<75>51,2,
IF(O11<100>76,3,
IF(O11<125>101,4))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use SUM on a single cell. SUM needs more than one cells to give you any results. Please read more about [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en-GB)

Also, you have to correct your formula to:

```
=IF(AND(O11>0,    O11<25),  "0", 
 IF(AND(O11>26,  O11<50), "1", 
 IF(AND(O11>51, O11<75), "2", 
 IF(AND(O11>76, O11<100), "3",
 IF(AND(O11>101, O11<125), "4", "???")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something along these lines (assuming your inputs are on cell O11)

=INT(O11/25)

Comment: Damn, quicker and faster than what i found : `=FLOOR(O11/25,1)`